# Stem plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to `plot(x, sin(x))` but instead of a line from `(xi,yi)` to `(x_i+1,y_i+1)` I want a vertical line to each point from `(xi,0)` to `(xi,yi)` as sometimes interpolation between the points makes no sense (e.g. quantized data) (and it looks much better with that vertical line than without).

Much like the stem plot below (from the matlab docs) but with the option of being able to turn off the circles and the "-" between points.
Unfortunately, I couldn't find an appropriate plotting function in the matplotlib documentation myself.

[image: stem plot]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a [stem plot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.stem.html?highlight=stem#matplotlib.pyplot.stem) (a.k.a. lollipop plot) in the matplotlib as well.

---

Below you can find an example from [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stem_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-stem-plot-py).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# returns 10 evenly spaced samples from 0.1 to 2*PI
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2 * np.pi, 10)

markerline, stemlines, baseline = plt.stem(x, np.cos(x), '-.')

# setting property of baseline with color red and linewidth 2
plt.setp(baseline, color='r', linewidth=2)

plt.show()
```

[image: stem plot]

---

If you want to adjust the y-position of the baseline, you can use the `bottom` parameter.

(adapted) Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# returns 10 evenly spaced samples from 0.1 to 2*PI
x = np.linspace(0.1, 2 * np.pi, 10)

plt.stem(x, np.cos(x), '-.', bottom=-2)

plt.show()
```

[image: stem plot 2]

Comment: Thanks now I need to figure out how to remove the blue circles.

Comment: @user948652 you only need to set the `markerfmt` parameter appropriately, e.g. `markerfmt='.'`. Just have a look at the documentation of the call parameters, it's nicely explained there.

Comment: is there a way to start the stems at negative infinity,  though?  I want something like this: https://namoseley.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/sin_poly_spectrum_small.png

Comment: @endolith You can use the `bottom` parameter to specify the y-position of the baseline.

Comment: @moooeeeep: Must be new?  `stem() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bottom'`

Comment: @endolith at least it is mentioned in the docs of matplotlib 1.1.1. I don't know about the implementation status in earlier versions. You can have a look at the function's source code (and try to add it to your codebase as a workaround) here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/axes.py

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use linestyle='steps--'

```
plot(x, sin(x), linestyle='steps--')
```

Comment: This is a horizontal step plot, doesn't do vertical lines like in the .gif link

Comment: My bad, I think @moooeeeep has it