# Numeric integration in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numerical-integration

I want to do something quite simple but I'm unable to find it in the depths of `numpy`.  I want to numerically and continuously integrate a function given by its values (*not* by its formula!).  That means I simply want an array which holds the sums of the beginning of the input array.  Example:

Input:

```
[ 4, 3, 5, 8 ]
```

Output:

```
[ 4, 7, 12, 20 ]  # [ sum(i[0:1]), sum(i[0:2]), sum(i[0:3]), sum(i[0:4]) ]
```

Sounds pretty straight forward, so I'm hopeful this must be easy with some `numpy` functionality I'm currently unable to find.

I found stuff like `scipy.integrate.quad()` but that seems to integrate over a given range (from a to b) and the returns a single value.  I need an array as output.

Comment: How is this integration?

Comment: The output are the values of the stemfunction of the function which produces the values of the input.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. For future readers: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145218/stem-plot-in-matplotlib)'s what a stem function looks like. Then we use Riemann sums.

Comment: @aryamccarthy Can you elaborate on why you would not consider a cumulative sum a numeric integration?  I don't see the point here and the link you provided wasn't helpful either.

Comment: I usually see numerical integration framed as having a function to evaluate, the way that [ode45](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) would. This cumulative summation is an important *part* of that process.

Comment: Numerical integration is the process of approximating an integral, given a domain and a function. Since you already have the stemfunction available, this question is not about numerical integration.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer You're mistaken.  I don't have the stemfunction available; I want to create it in the process.  By that I mean its values, not its formula.  Hence integration.  But call it as you like.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `numpy.cumsum`:

```
   >>> numpy.cumsum([ 4, 3, 5, 8 ])
   array([ 4,  7, 12, 20])
```

Answer (score 7):

You would simply need [`numpy.cumsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html).

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ 4, 3, 5, 8 ])
print np.cumsum(a) # prints [ 4  7 12 20]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (`pip install quadpy`), a project of mine, which as opposed to `scipy.integrate.quad()` does vectorized compution. Provide it with many intervals, and get all the integral values over these intervals back.

```py
import numpy
import quadpy

a = 0.0
b = 3.0
h = 1.0e-2
n = int((b-a) / h)

x0 = numpy.linspace(a, b, num=n, endpoint=False)
x1 = x0 + h
intervals = numpy.stack([x0, x1])

vals = quadpy.line_segment.integrate(
        lambda x: numpy.sin(x),
        intervals,
        quadpy.line_segment.GaussLegendre(5)
        )

res = numpy.cumsum(vals)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(x1, numpy.sin(x1), label='f')
plt.plot(x1, res, label='F')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice!  But actually I just have a bunch of numbers I want to continually sum up (and by now I know that `np.cumsum()` does that.  Someone, however, found my wording for this (numerical integration) so misleading that he rephrased my question so fundamentally that in the end it looked like I was searching for functions.  I undid that (in my eyes way too rigorous) change.  I guess your answer was given during that period.

Comment: @Nico You cannot just edit a question such that it allows you to write an answer, the main goal of which seems to be promoting your software.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for the reply. The question was very unclear, specifically its connection to numerical integration; see the discussion below the original post. From `I don't have the stemfunction available; I want to create it in the process. [...]`, I gathered that the question is really about that. I proceeded to edit the post accordingly, and after some tinkering gave an answer, namely one that creates the antiderivative. I indeed use a package that I wrote, but I don't see what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `numpy` to get the output. Using standard [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) we get the following:

```py
from itertools import accumulate

a = [4, 3, 5, 8]
*b, = accumulate(a)
print(b) 

# [4, 7, 12, 20]
```

Comment: I am using `numpy` for performance reasons.  I'm summing up millions of samples.  Otherwise the `itertools` approach could of course be feasible.