# Dashed lines from points to axes in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of points which I am plotting like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,4,9,16,25,36]

plt.scatter(x, y)

plt.show()
```

This gives output like this

[image]

What I want is to drop perpendiculars from the points to the axes, like in the figure below:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 30):

Using `hlines` and `vlines` you can plot horizontal and vertical lines respectively.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [1,4,9,16,25,36]

plt.vlines(x, 0, y, linestyle="dashed")
plt.hlines(y, 0, x, linestyle="dashed")
plt.scatter(x, y, zorder=2)

plt.xlim(0,None)
plt.ylim(0,None)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plot you're looking for is what's known as a stemplot, which has an answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13145218/stem-plot-in-matplotlib#13145410). It will give you the vertical line connections to the x-axis you desire; but if you want the horizontal lines connecting to the y-axis that may need some special treatment. You may be able to use a stem plot in the other axis rotated or something.

Comment: I was looking for a more generic solution: for example can the elements in the two arrays passed to a function which will draw dashed lines between to arbitrary points: in this case (x,y) to (x,0) for vertical lines, and (x,y) to (0, y) for horizontal lines, so that both cases are covered